# How do I iterate over all lines of files passed on the command line?

Tags: python, stdin

I usually do this in Perl:

whatever.pl

```
while(<>) {
    #do whatever;
}
```

then `cat foo.txt | whatever.pl`

Now, I want to do this in Python. I tried `sys.stdin` but I have no idea how to do as I have done in Perl. How can I read the input?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

Comment: +1 This way is more flexible than "for line in sys.stdin", as it will work for filenames pass as cmd line arguments.

Answer (score 13):

```
import sys
def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print line
if __name__=='__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: -1: main returns None -- it's not *perfectly* clear what value should be returned to the OS.

Comment: This is how I normally do it, but it only iterates over stdin while OP wanted to iterate over all the files named on the command line. For that use case, fileinput is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    # do stuff w/line
```

Answer (score 0):

Don Werve's answer of:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

is excellent, and probably exactly what you're looking for.  However, be aware that if you use it as-is you can encounter snags when using it with the `argparse` module, or if you specify any command-line switches when running your script.

For example, if you run:

```
./my_script.py --verbose file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

you'll get an error message saying that there is no such file named `--verbose`.  So what do to if you're using command-line switches?

What you have to do is isolate the input files in a list, and them pass them into the `files` argument of `fileinput.input()`.  And if you're using the `argparse` module, you can extract the `input_files` like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('input_files', nargs='*')

# Extract out command-line information:
args = parser.parse_args()
verbose = args.verbose
input_files = args.input_files
```

From here, we can pass our `input_files` into `fileinput.input()` with the `files=` argument:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(files=input_files):
    process(line)
```

What's nice about this is that if no input files are specified when calling your script, then `input_files` will be an empty list.  And when you pass in an empty list as the `files=` argument, then `fileinput.input()` will iterate over `sys.stdin`.

That's very convenient, as it behaves very similarly to Perl's `while (<>) { ... }` construct.

---

Of course, you only need to consider this if there are arguments in your command-line that do not represent files to be read in.  That is, if every single one of your arguments are always treated as files to be read in, then the following typical solution listed at the top of `pydoc fileinput` works perfectly fine:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

I hate to beat a dead horse, but may I suggest using a pure function?

```
import sys

def main(stdin):
  for line in stdin:
    print("You said: " + line.strip())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.stdin)
```

This approach is nice because main is dependent purely on its input and you can unit test it with anything that obeys the line-delimited input stream paradigm.