# Python equivalent of Perl's while (<>) {...}?

Tags: python, stdin

I write a lot of little scripts that process files on a line-by-line basis. In Perl, I use

```
while (<>) {
    do stuff;
}
```

This is handy because it doesn't care where the input comes from (a file or stdin).

In Python I use this

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2: # there's a command line argument
    sys.stdin = file(sys.argv[1])
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    do stuff
```

which doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a Python idiom that easily handles file/stdin input?

Comment: From a "readable code" point of view, I'd prefer your Python code as most people not working with Perl won't know what the Perl code means.

Comment: You can at least omit .readlines()

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715277/how-do-i-iterate-over-all-lines-of-files-passed-on-the-commandline-in-python

Comment: The perl version isn't elegant, its just shorter.  Like schnaader said, its highly unreadable to anyone who doesn't know perl.

Comment: French is highly unreadable to anyone who doesn't know French.

Comment: Ah, yes, but the python is somewhat readable to someone who knows English :)

Comment: the statement "French is highly unreadable to anyone who doesn't know French" is wrong, if you know latin !

Comment: `for line in sys.stdin.readlines():` is a bad example, as it reads the whole file into memory and creates a list of strings. Using the line iterator in the file is better practice: `for line in sys.stdin:`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The fileinput module in the standard library is just what you want:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(): ...
```

Comment: Indeed. Thanks a million. Sorry I missed the other question that deals with the same problems. Was hard to find with this tite...

Answer (score 16):

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty.

Comment: I'm using the arguments for other purposes, can I disable that behavior?

Comment: @user1552512 Yes, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html : `To specify an alternative list of filenames, pass it as the first argument to input(). A single file name is also allowed.`

Answer (score 7):

[fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) defaults to stdin, so would make it slightly more concise.

If you do a lot of command-line stuff, though, this [piping hack](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/276960/) is very neat.