# Is there a more pythonic way to open a file if given one as an argument or stdin if not?

Tags: python, unix, command-line

I'm trying to write a python script which follows the common unix command line pattern of accepting input from stdin if no file name is given.  This is what I've been using:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        stream = open(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        stream = sys.stdin
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do that?

Comment: Duplicate of [Python equivalent of Perl's while (<>) {…}?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807173/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module is perfect for this.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

For bonus points do you have any tips on how nicely it plays with [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)?

Answer (score 5):

similar but one-line solution

```
stream = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv)>1 else sys.stdin
```

Comment: Won't `len(sys.argv)` *always* be at least one (the script name is `argv[0]`)?

Answer (score 2):

how about this one?

```
stream=sys.argv[1:] and open(sys.argv[1]) or sys.stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make it more unixy instead:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    sys.stdin = open(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: -1: this makes sys.stdin change semantics (see the documentation for the sys module), and breaks expectations.  This therefore makes the code less legible (someone who misses the change of sys.stdin would infer that the program does not read an input file argument).